# Datedifference in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I m using the below query to get time difference between 2 records of time

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY TimeStamp)
  FROM AISDb
)
SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp) 
  FROM x INNER JOIN x AS y 
  ON x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID
  AND x.rn = y.rn - 1
  WHERE x.Action = 'OUT'
  AND y.Action = 'IN';
```

```
ID   Name         PERSONRFID                   ACTION  LOGREAD  TIMESTAMP      DATESTAMP

1  Kashif Islam E20010018303014826000F5A    IN  True    20:43:00    1/16/2013

8  Kashif Islam E20010018303014826000F5A    IN  True    12:22:00    1/26/2013

10 Kashif Islam E20010018303014826000F5A    OUT True    12:22:00    1/26/2013

11 Aamir Munir  E20010018303020025901029    IN  True    12:22:00    1/26/2013

15 Aamir Munir  E20010018303020025901029    OUT True    11:46:00    1/29/2013

25 Kashif Islam E20010018303014826000F5A    OUT True    12:41:00    1/29/2013
```

the problem is that i get fine result for the same day as i m making a IN OUT pair for same day. But if it donot find the next OUT in the same day for e.g in case where ID is 1 on date 1/16/2013, it donot get a OUT action and so it make a pair with ID 25. Which should not be done. So in short i need the query to take care of the date also and make IN OUT paper for same date and if not then ignore.kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a comparison on the date:

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY TimeStamp)
  FROM AISDb
)
SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp) 
FROM x INNER JOIN
      x AS y 
     ON x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID and
        x.rn = y.rn - 1 and
        x.Action = 'OUT' and
        y.Action = 'IN' and
        cast(x.timestamp as date) = cast(y.timestamp as date);
```

I'm using the SQL Server syntax for doing the conversion to date.

If you want all 'X' records, even when there is no matching Y, the you need a left outer join.  I would write the query as:

```
SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp) 
FROM x INNER JOIN
      x AS y 
     ON x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID and
        x.rn = y.rn - 1 and
        y.Action = 'IN' and
        cast(x.timestamp as date) = cast(y.timestamp as date);
where x.Action = 'OUT'
```